# Unable to save block changes using Page Builder in 2.4.5 EE

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, cms, magento2.4.5, page-builder

I'm Unable to save block changes using Page Builder in Magento 2.4.5 EE

Issue mostly found in google chrome, brave, edge all with windows operating systems.
however i tried to replicate the issue in firefox and never got to see it there.
The issue occurs randomly, where the changes made in Page Builder do not update even after saving the block, and the old values persist.

I'm running magento 2.4.5 EE in production mode with js minification enabled.

I'm also getting some console errors in browser but not in firefox, not sure if this is related.
[image: console error in google chrome]

I have a video of the [incident](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/17019490?key=80857084be2fb32a7a166555dc6fa327) : https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/17019490?key=80857084be2fb32a7a166555dc6fa327

Also found a related [github issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25620): https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25620

Comment: I am getting the exact same problem. Its very confusing. We can only use firefox to make updates. We also discovered old versions for Chrome will work. Running newest version of Chrome does not work. We are on 2.4.5p2 Steps
1. Goto content page
2. Open pagebuilder
3. Add some new text
4. Hits Save
5. Go back into content section in pagebuilder - changes not there

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check [This](https://github.com/mirasvit/module-blog/issues/162) Link

In this link, you Found [Patch](https://github.com/mirasvit/module-blog/issues/162#issuecomment-561644854).